# Is there any data supporting a correlation between carpal tunnels and using keyboard-heavy editors like Emacs or Vim?

Tags: vim, emacs, ergonomics

I have some predisposing factors to developing carpal tunnel and would like to avoid it as much as possible. I do however want to use Vim or Emacs and I would like to learn from the experiences of others.

Has there been any research showing either a correlation or lack of correlation between using a keyboard-heavy editor like Vim or Emacs and developing carpal tunnel syndrome?

Comment: I'm not clear how this is primarily opinion-based. It is either true that Vim has a higher probability than Emacs to cause CTS or not. Whether people have different opinions on this is irrelevant to the truth, if people choose to answer it with their opinion rather than their experience their answer should be ignored or deleted. If no one is eligible to answer this question based on experience then it will remain unanswered.

Comment: Independently from editors, key moves for me were 1) to learn a new keyboard map (the french bépo ~= dvorak) 2) to buy a small ergonomic keyboard (a typematrix). And I now use Emacs with evil-mode as to reduce weird keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 5):

Emacs uses a lot of combination key strokes, especially ctrl. Many emacs users bind ctrl to the caps-lock key to make it easy to access with the left pinky. Still if you are worried about carpal tunnel I think less one combo keys would be better, especailly if you tend to do them one handed.

I haven't used vim intensively but from what I remember from mys sysadmin days, it's mostly single keys, although esc is frequent and is a stretch. You could move the esc key and end up with a fairly neutral typing position for most tasks in vim.